# Why NaBH4 don't reduce this keto group?

Tags: carbonyl-compounds, organic-reduction

I was solving problems related to Carbonyls. The question was:

> What would be the product formed after the reduction of this compound
> using $\ce{NaBH4}$?
>
> [image]
>
> (This is an isomer of Glutaric Anhydride)

I thought that $\ce{NaBH4}$ will reduce the keto group (not the ester) but my book said there will be no reduction. When I asked my instructor he said "Since there are many Oxygen due to steric and some other reason it won't reduce". Won't $\ce{NaBH4}$ reduce that? if-else Why so?

Comment: Which book is this from?

Comment: @Waylander It is actually from our coaching material for "JEE".

Comment: Your instructor's explanation is unconvincing

Comment: @Waylander Yeah.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is no evidence in the literature that this won't be reduced by NaBH4. You are being asked to explain a "fact" which nobody has ever observed before.

Comment: @orthocresol Yes Actually, I assumed that it will reduce but it is in the book that told the compound won't be reduced by NaBH4. Only LiAlH4 can reduce it.